# Pandas - Subtract one column from other columns in same dataframe for multiple files with varying column names and number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to subtract the 3rd from the right column from all other columns except for itself and the last column, then create new columns with these values with the header including the original column's header. The column names and the number of columns between each file vary, but the names of the 2 most right columns are always the same.

Example df:

| ROI005 | ROI008 | 53141 | AVG | ERR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 2 |

Desired output:

| ROI005 | ROI008 | 53141 | AVG | ERR | ROI005 - Background | ROI008 - Background | Average - Background |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

I've been using this to get the difference for the 3rd to last column using the below code. I know that I can use `df.iloc[ : , : -3]` for all but the last 3 columns, but I'm not sure how to combine this with `df.iloc[ : , -2]` for multiple columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Me\1Test' + '/*.txt')
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_table(f)
    df['Average - Background']  = df.iloc[ : , -2] - df.iloc[ : , -3]
    df.to_excel(f.replace('txt', 'xlsx'), 'Sheet1')
```

Data:

```
{'ROI005': [2, 4, 3],
 'ROI008': [5, 2, 3],
 '53141': [1, 2, 1],
 'AVG': [4, 3, 5],
 'ERR': [1, 3, 2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

We could subtract that particular column from the other columns horizontally using `sub` on `axis=0`; then `join` it back to `df`:

```
out = (df.join(df.drop(df.columns[[-3,-1]], axis=1)
               .sub(df[df.columns[-3]], axis=0)
               .add_suffix(' - Background')))
```

Output:

```
   ROI005  ROI008  53141  AVG  ERR  ROI005 - Background  ROI008 - Background   AVG - Background  
0       2       5      1    4    1                    1                    4                  3  
1       4       2      2    3    3                    2                    0                  1
2       3       3      1    5    2                    2                    2                  4
```

Comment: How can I put this into my code? Sorry, I'm pretty new to coding. I've updated my original post with my full code. I tried substituting your suggestion with `df['Average - Background']  = df.iloc[ : , -2] - df.iloc[ : , -3]` but the output I get are just .txt files converted to .xlsx with no other changes.

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'out_excel'"

Comment: @CodingIsFun sorry, let’s try: `out.to_excel('file.xlsx')` and see if anything is saved.